# Navbar is off when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

When I'm in localhost the application looks good but once its deployed to heroku something seems off with the navbar and the content. I'm not sure why.

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH2bD.png Localhost

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJx83.png Heroku

Comment: Please share the relevant code. Or if its not an issue then share the live url.

Comment: Sorry! Here is the url. I don't think the code should be relevant if the localhost shows it without a problem?

Comment: http://young-mountain-9514.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BIwA.png

No issues here. It looks the same as the one you shared for `localhost`. I would recommend clearing your browser cache then reopen the browser.

Comment: Hey, just saw this 7 years later. Lol!

Thank you!